# cron job with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cron, cakephp-1.3

I have referred http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/calling-controller-actions-from-cron-and-the-command-line and created cron_dispatcher.php and placed it in the app folder.

I have return some test email function for the cron job to run in my users controller's test method.

And i have created a Cron job in my web server's control panel like

```
"/usr/bin/php/home4/enventur/public_html/pennystock/cron_dispatcher.php /users/test"
```

But its giving me an error as "No input file specified."

Please help me, how to solve it ??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190145/cakephp-running-controller-action-as-a-cron-job-not-working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done it in different way,

Please see the steps, it may helpful for others..

Cron/Shell Using Cakephp Framework Structure:

1. create

   `F:\websites\projectname\app\vendors\shells\filename.php`

   ```
   class ClassName extends Shell {
       //var $uses = array('Post'); //name of Model

       //Main function runs always when shell executes
       function main() {
           mail("nidhin@2basetechnologies.com","Test","Test");
       }
   }
   ```

2.set 754 permission to `F:\websites\projectname\cake\console\cake`

3. Set cron job as `/home4/enventur/public_html/pennystock/cake/console/cake -app "/home4/enventur/public_html/pennystock/app" ClassName >/dev/null 2>&1`

   > /dev/null 2>&1: for Suppressing warning/error/msg from server

Thank you
Nidhin

Comment: I have tried your solution, but unfortunately it gives me an error: `Error: Class TestingShell could not be loaded.` And I have done everything exactly as you described. Do you have any idea why isn't this working? Thank you!

Comment: I rolled back to the previous version of Cake and not it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: can anyone just post me how to set crontab easily with an example??

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like PHP cannot find the file you specified. Check that the path is correct. For example:

```
# incorrect path
/home4/enventur/public_html/pennystock/cron_dispatcher.php

# correct path (?)
/home4/enventur/public_html/pennystock/app/cron_dispatcher.php
```

Now, this next part doesn't directly answer your question, but it's worth noting that [CakePHP shells](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/The-CakePHP-Console.html#creating-shells-tasks) are intended for this exact purpose.

If you created a shell called `Mailer` and copied your `UsersController::test()` code to `MailerShell::test()`, you would call that from `cron` like this (again, check the paths are correct):

`/home4/enventur/public_html/pennystock/cake/console/cake -app /home4/enventur/public_html/pennystock/app mailer test`

With this approach, you wouldn't have to use `cron_dispatcher.php` as noted in that ancient Bakery article (written for CakePHP 1.1 on Christmas 4 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

The cron job is a long running process that executes commands at specific dates and times.

Go to your domain cpanel account.

First make the file which you want to run the code using cron job. and upload the file on your website root folder.

Now Go to "Cron job" section in your cpanel account and enter the file path in textbox and set the time shedule which you want to run the file.

Thanks.