# CakePHP Shell cronjob: Error: Class TestingShell could not be loaded

Tags: cakephp, cron

I am trying to get a cronjob in CakePHP work. But I am getting this error: `Error: Class TestingShell could not be loaded.`

Here is my `/app/vendors/shells/testing.php` file:

```
class TestingShell extends Shell    {
var $uses = array('Test');
function main(){
    $this->out('Number of tests :');
    $this->out($this->Test->find('count'));
    $this->out('.');
    if($this->Test->delete(1)){
        $this->out('test deleted'); 
    }
    else{
        $this->out('test not deleted'); 
    }
}
```

}

I am calling the cronjob like this: `/home/root/public_html/site/cake/console/cake -app /home/root/public_html/site/app testing`

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much!

**EDIT** I must add that, locally, the shell works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this bug report -- this was my problem.

http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1601-cakephp-138-console-ignores-app-parameter

Rolling back to 1.3.7 was the quick fix.

Comment: You are golden! Thank you very much! Now it works! However, it still gives me an error, `TERM environment variable not set.`, but it does its job. Why is it throwing this error? And also, why isn't the 1.3.8 version working? How can it be resolved? Will I be able to make updates to Cake in future or will I face again this odd behaviour with the cronjob not working?

Comment: I believe they already fixed it in the development branch.  I would expect 1.3.9 to work fine.  The TERM environment thing is unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this, you may also need the added shell script

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1110/Running-Shells-as-cronjobs

you also have the params wrong way round, its

`1 * * * * cake/path scritp params -app app/path`

Comment: I am not following that tutorial. I guided upon this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192070/cron-job-with-cakephp . Anyway, I have tried this `/home/root/public_html/site/cake/console/cake testing -app /home/root/public_html/site/app` and it still doesn't work...the same error. I am quite a newbie to all cronjob/Linux/command line stuff, so I really don't get what is going wrong. But since it gives me that error, I believe the script found that it should be a TestingShell class somewhere (based on the `testing` command I wrote), but it couldn't find it.