# CakePHP v1.3.13 : Error Class Shell Could not be loaded (Linux Server)

Tags: php, cakephp, cron

i have an app made from cakephp 1.3.13 and it needs to run the shell script (as cron job). i've run the script locally on my local machine and it looks good, but when i tried in on live is says **Error Class Shell Could not be loaded ** i tried the solutions from [CakePHP Shell cronjob: Error: Class TestingShell could not be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809210/cakephp-shell-cronjob-error-class-testingshell-could-not-be-loaded), [Cakephp shell :Shell class HelloShell could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671634/cakephp-shell-shell-class-helloshell-could-not-be-found), [cakephp Error: Class WidgetShell could not be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989125/cakephp-error-class-widgetshell-could-not-be-loaded)

it doesn't solve my problem. i also change the permission on the server of my script but it also doesn't work. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are missing something when running your shell script. try this one

```
path/to/app_name# ./cake/console/cake shell_script_name -app app
```